# How do I delete or modify a line in a text file if it matches the string in my combo box C#

Tags: c#

So I have a combo box that contains a list of trainees that is imported from a textfile (each trainee occupies a line in the textfile) and I have 3 buttons, add (adds a new trainee to the file and combobox), delete(Supposed to delete the specific line in the file containing the combobox selected item) and a modify button (supposed to overwrite a new trainee in the file at the same line that contains the combobox selected item), my add button works fine, idk how to modify or delete lines in a file.

I have no idea how to work this around as I'm new to working with files

here's my code

```
        private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("trainee.txt", FileMode.Open);
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
                }
            }
            fs.Close();
        }

 private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Choose a trainee to delete.", "Error !");
            }
            else
            {
                string selection = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                FileStream fs = new FileStream("stagiaire.txt", FileMode.Open);
                List<string> lines = new List<string>();
                using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) == selection)
                    {

                    }
                }
                fs.Close();

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Choose a trainee to modify.", "Error !");
            }
            else
            {
                string selection = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                FileStream fs = new FileStream("trainee.txt", FileMode.Open);
                List<string> lines = new List<string>();
                using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs))
                {
                    string line;
                    if ((line = r.ReadLine()) == selection)
                    {
                        Trainee stg = new Trainee();
                        stg.name = textBox1.Text;
                        stg.nickname = textBox2.Text;
                        stg.training_days = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                        addtrainee(stg);
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(stg);
                    }
                }
                fs.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Your options, 1) use a database, 2) recreate the file any time something changes 3) see option 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be working too hard, the List you have is working for you here.  Whenever you need to output it, just write the whole list.  When you need to manipulate the entries in it (elements), use the collection methods like Find, Contains, Add, Remove, others see (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2#methods)

You can shortcut you file access too, use the framework:

```
var fileLines = File.ReadLines("c:/temp/yourfile.txt");
```

No using and StreamReader/Writer needed, depending on your environment too I guess.

So you have your input as string and `List<string>` so you could do `if (lines.Contains(testString))` for example.

Can provide more sample code if it helps.

Comment: I have a general idea on what to do now, its quite easier to manipulate the list where i put the object trainee then save it to the file, thanks a lot.